# Google Maps API - Draggable markers, but only along certain path

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How do I make a marker in Google Maps API that can be dragged only along a specified path? I only need to do it in the shape of a circle.
Can't find anything specifically related on SO.

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oh4v583t/1/

```
maybe using marker.setpath function?;
```

Comment: Checked `SnapToRoute` implementation in the example?

Comment: The example has everything you need.

Comment: I havent the first clue though how to implement this from the DirectionsRenderer to a polyline/shape. I know it should be far simpler but I haven't the first clue about any of the functions used in that example.

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/oh4v583t/1/) is from the question: [Google Maps API v3 - Draggable Marker Along a Polyline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816185/google-maps-api-v3-draggable-marker-along-a-polyline)